# Different behavior between Python 2 and 3 of vars() in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I am currently converting a script from Python 2 to Python 3. While debugging it, I stumbled upon a part of the code that behaves differently between both versions. However, I am unable to explain this difference.

Here is a reproducer:

```py
variable_1 = "x"
variable_2 = "y"
list_of_variables = ['variable_1', 'variable_2']
existing_variables = vars()

print([variable for variable in list_of_variables if variable in vars()])
print([variable for variable in list_of_variables if variable in existing_variables])
```

Python 2.7.18 shows the following output:

```
['variable_1', 'variable_2']
['variable_1', 'variable_2']
```

Whereas Python 3.9.0 displays:

```
[]
['variable_1', 'variable_2']
```

Why is the first list comprehension not working in Python 3? And why is it working when storing the content of `vars()` within a variable?

Comment: I suspect you're trying to do something that's an antipattern. "list of variables" is just a list of strings.. If you want to store named elements with values, use a dictionary, not a list

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's working in both: it's just working *differently*.

In Python 3, list comprehensions create their own local scope to avoid leaking variable names into the calling scope. The call to `vars()` inside the list comprehension is just returning the variables defined in the list comprehension's own scope, not the scope where the list comprehension is used.

From https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries:

> However, aside from the iterable expression in the leftmost for clause, the comprehension is executed in a separate implicitly nested scope. This ensures that names assigned to in the target list don’t “leak” into the enclosing scope.

Answer (score 0):

In python 3, vars() acts like locals(), which means your locals() is different inside the list comprehension.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars